# CSS Grid - How to get overflow to work only on the middle row (of a 3 row grid)?

Tags: html, css

I have a grid with 3 rows (header, main, footer).

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header, .main, .footer {
  background-color: #20262e;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.main {
  min-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="main">Main</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

I want the header and footer to always be fixed to the top and bottom of their respective containers, and have the middle (main row) to have a overflow scrollbar when the content would otherwise go off screen.

I'm having trouble getting the overflow to work on the main container.

http://jsfiddle.net/fysar4e1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `100vh` for the `wrapper` which makes the height fill the page, and use `calc` to calculate the `main` div.

In order to make it work all modern browsers you need to add `Normalize.css` to the page, it'll reset the default values set on various browsers. I've tested this on Chrome and Firefox browser and it works.
218px is the sum of all vertical `paddings` and `margins` and `height` of `header` and `footer`:

```
height: calc(100vh - 218px);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: calc(100vh - 56px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header, .main, .footer {
  background-color: #20262e;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.main {
  height: calc(100vh - 218px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="main">Main
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```